# Arguments/Struct compatibility when calling a dynamic library on OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, dynamic, struct, arguments

I have 2 separate projects on OSX:
-the first is a MachO Dynamic Library project in XCode. 
It has a function that is being called with an argument (a struct). 
-the second is a Qt application project in Qt Creator. 
It loads the dynamic library and calls the function, passing a struct as an argument.

Of course both share the same declaration of that function and struct.

The problem is, when I call the function, the values in the struct received in the function have nothing to do with the values I sent from the application. A simple printf before calling the function and another one within the function shows completely different values.

What did I did wrong?

My struct is composed of the following elements :
-multiple std::string
-multiple int
-multiple char[64]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an incompatibility with std::string, something about compiler flags/library that change the way std::string are implemented. I just changed everything to char[].